# Enable elastic scrolling / overscrolling on element, but not on body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a web app that's designed to be packaged into node-webkit, so it's laid out more like an app with embedded scrollviews and less like a large, scrollable website.

I've disabled elastic scrolling (overscrolling) on my body and main container by setting

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I'd like to re-enable elastic scrolling for several of the divs I have inside the app. These divs are sized to take up the full screen height, and have overflow:scroll styles:

```
somediv {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

so that content inside them scrolls.

Currently, both momentum scrolling and elastic scrolling are disabled inside these divs. Is there a way to re-enable overscrolling, but only inside these elements?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some **specific height** to the elements you want scrolling and for those elements add css property **overflow-y:scroll**

For example:

```
somediv {
   height: 350px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

That's it..!!